# Is execution time of same program for multiple time give different result?

Tags: java, clock

I have measure the execution time of my program using System.nanoTime() function. For every execution it is giving different execution time. Also i have measure the no of clock cycles by multiplying it with the processor speed. And due to different execution time the no of clock cycles coming is also different. I don't know whether it is correct or i am doing wrong somewhere. Plz suggest the answer.

Comment: Many factors can affect the execution time of your program (JVM startup, class loading, JIT compilation, other applications using CPU etc.). Without more details it is difficult to say.

Comment: You are microbenchmarking on the JVM, it seems. It's a black art, you can't just "do it" the obvious way.

Comment: There will be variances based on all sorts of parameters, such as what is going on on that computer right now, is there other programs running is the garbage collector running. Try taking a average over say 25 runs and then do it again

Comment: @AbstractChaos Just 25 runs? No, no. The JIT kicks in by default after 10,000 iterations :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik true was just an example as I was unsure of the length of time the program took to run. (if it takes 5 mins to run then 10k iterations would take a month to complete :P )

Comment: @AbstractChaos Yes, one poor-man's approach is to do run after run, displaying the times. Then you'll notice a sudden jump in the timing---that's when the JIT did its job.

Comment: This is correct, if unfortunate as you don't have a real time system.  You can only say how long a single run took.  Even if you do nothing between two calls to System.nanoTime() you can see variation and up to 5 ms delay if there was a context switch.  You might find this interesting  http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/micro-jitter-busy-waiting-and-binding.html The first chart shows the count of delays of a range of latencies between repeated calls to System.nanoTime() in an hour.  You can see there are many in the milli-seconds.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is wrong. Your line of questioning indicates you do not understand how processors and clock cycles work, even at a rudimentary level.

There is no way to measure processor speed by timing how long it takes to execute a java program.

Comment: This is a bit too unqualified. It can be done with a fairly high accuracy, but it takes a lot of expertise and care.

Comment: if you can suggest me how to do it then it will be better

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in your assumption:

First the value returned by `System.nanoTime()` has a resolution of nanoseconds but not necessarily the precision. It is possible that the value is only updated once per millisecond (this is implementation dependent).

Next is that you're meassuring wall clock time. The time elapsed depends highly on your system load. You never know which processes also take processing time or not. Therefore you cannot calculate from the wall time to any execution speed directly.

Third you assume that a certain number of Java commands equal always to the same number of processor instructions. This is wrong. E.g. Hotspot can reorder your commands or even compile your code in the meantime and optimize the compiled code several times.